# Reports in VS - Data Source instance not being detected?

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset

So I have made a dataset and chart in visual studio. I have then added the report viewer to the page and added the datasource instance. But when I run the page I get an error: "A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'"

Here is my code for both the sql query which is the datasource instance and the code for the reportviewer.

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptpassfails" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ShowBackButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowPageNavigationControls="False" ShowZoomControl="False" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\chart_passfails.rdlc" DisplayName="dspassfail" ReportEmbeddedResource="Qsis.Reports.chart_passfails.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                        <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="sqlpassfail" Name="passfail" runat="server"/>

          </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlpassfail" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT
  StudentModule.StudentPassFailModule
  ,[Module].ModuleCode
  ,Course.CourseName
  ,Course.School
  ,Course.EntryYear
FROM
  [Module]
  INNER JOIN StudentModule
    ON [Module].ModuleId = StudentModule.ModuleId
  INNER JOIN Course
    ON [Module].CourseId = Course.CourseId
        Where Course.CourseName=@course AND Course.EntryYear=@entryyear">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="entryyear" QueryStringField="entryyear" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="course" QueryStringField="course" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the code behind look like?

Comment: There is no code behind. Everything is added in the .aspx file. For the parameters would I have to add them in the code behind?

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure. When I use the Report Viewer, I specify the Report Server URL in the code behind. `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://sqlreport/reportserver")`

Comment: Are you registering your assembly for the ReportViewer in your aspx page?